# How do I get Fielddata and Origin Summary on the PageSpeed insights working?

Tags: pagespeed-insights, google-pagespeed-insights-api

First I want to thank everybody for the great support and the good tutorials from google to improve the quality of our websites. Right now we are working on an update of our websites because the core web vitals are bad.
I learned a lot by reading this forum and the turorials online but there is one issue which I can't solve or where I don't find an answer to.

How do I get Fielddata and Origin Summary on the PageSpeed insights working?

Is it basically just an issure because there need to be a specific amout of users on your website using chrome or do I have to set something up  to collect the data

If it is just a specific number, does anyone know how many users you need?

I've set up google analytics, which delivers data. During my investigations I found out, that I need to add the Chorme UX Report in the Data Studio (https://web.dev/chrome-ux-report-data-studio-dashboard/).

I have sucessfully added the google analytics connector to the data studio. But when I want to add the connector I get the error:
"If your origin is not included in the CrUX dataset, you may get an error message like the one below. There are over 4 million origins in the dataset, but the one you want may not have sufficient data to be included."

The error is descriped on this page: https://web.dev/chrome-ux-report-data-studio-dashboard/ but there is no solution?

So how can I add the origin to the CrUX dataset?

I already started to implement a google cloud project with BigQuery but I'm not sure if this is really neccessary to get the field data.

It feels like that I'm missing out one esential step.

Maybe you can help me mit what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you in advance Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How do I get my site included in the CrUX data?

It is down to traffic numbers and what browser, preferences etc. visitors to your site have.

You can't influence inclusion in the data set (as far as I am aware*), it will happen naturally as your site traffic grows.

So for now ignore trying to get the data from the CrUX dataset and instead focus on gathering your own Real User Metrics (RUM).

### Gather your own Real User Metrics (measurements) - or RUM

You can do this using the [web vitals library](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals) quite easily, allowing you to gather real world data which will be almost identical to the CrUX data that is collected (for browsers other than Chrome too!).

You can also [pipe the results directly to Google Analytics](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals#send-the-results-to-google-analytics) if you don't want to build your own API.

The only metric you don't get is [speed index](https://web.dev/speed-index/) due to the way it is calculated, but the other 5 metrics are more than sufficient to monitor the performance of your site.

### Getting even more data than CrUX or the web vitals library allows

Or if you want to get really fancy you can use the [`performanceObserver` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceObserver) to gather loads of raw data such as paint times, layout shifts, resources timings etc. and calculate your own metrics.

Although this is a **lot** of work (you have to research how to calculate each metric etc. It took me a good few weeks to get it right!) the advantage is you can analyse the data for things like Cumulative Layout Shifts happening at a particular screen size (assuming you track this information as well) easily, something that is very difficult using purely the CrUX data or the Web Vitals Library.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and great answer. That helped me a lot. 

I will try to the first version for the beginning and maybe Im later look at the API.

Comment: Not a problem, glad it helped! Good luck with the project(s).